# Docker Angular not loading

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I have create docker composer yml with angular and laravel ,laravel is up and when i got to see angular console in docker is running perfectly ,but in browser its not loading

My docker File

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My Docker COmposer File

```
version: "3"

networks:
  zervetek:


services:
  backend:
    build: ./zervtek-backend
    container_name: zervetek_back
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./zervtek-backend:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - zervetek
    depends_on:
      - database
      - phpmyadmin

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: zervetek_front
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - zervetek
    depends_on:
      - backend

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=databse
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - zervetek

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8088:80
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=database
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    networks:
      - zervetek
```

My docker log file

[image]

Any idea why is not loading on browser

Comment: Did you double checked 4200 port on your host?

Comment: lsof -i:4200,if you are on LInux.

Comment: Share more details : os, version, etc. Also create a hello world reproducing your sample to help you. I built complex angular app using docker without any problem

Comment: Yeah i double checked on 4200, the page is not working
, and am using windows
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro,
OS Version:                10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045,

docker version
 Version:           20.10.10

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `EXPOSE 4200` to your dockerfile.

This is the important part from the documentation (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose):

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on the specified network ports at runtime.

**Suggestion:** I am not quiet sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to use this docker image for production, you should change your approach to only copy the compiles output to the docker image and use some server like nginx to serve the actual files.

Comment: I added expose in docker file still same issue